# How to ignore a directory from pull on remote repository

Tags: git, yii2, gitignore

We are working on a yii2 project and have a git repository. But every time each on team member pull from remote repo some files are replaced,such as common/main-local.php, common/params-local.php and all the files inside backend/runtime and debug.

How we prevent from rewriting these files when pulling from remote repo?

I look in backend/runtime and see a .gitignore file but inside it there were just to line:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

there are some similar files on some other directories. I guess these ignore file will prevent from pulling but it seems they don't.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't ignore files while pulling it. Instead you should add these files in your .gitignore files, so that they won't be committed and pushed to remote repos.

If these files are already in your remote repo, then you should remove them using,

git rm --cached common/main-local.php

git rm --cached common/params-local.php

If you want to remove the common directory then,

In .gitignore add,

common/**

And remove the directory,

git rm --cached -r common

Now make a new commit and push. These files will be deleted from the remote repo too.